# Unable to install bootloader on MotoDroid with froyo FRG83D

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, motorola-droid, rooting

I'm attempting to root my phone and have placed an update.zip in the root of my SDCard.  I get the message that the zip is not signed and the update fails.

I understand that VZN started added this checksum to make sure that only official OTA's can get installed.  Does anyone know howto get past this so that I can root my phone, so that I can install cyanogenMod, so that I can do wifi hotspot tethering?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a bad file, either from a bad source or it just got corrupted.  I would try again.  Follow [this tutorial on DroidForums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/hacking-help/67546-so-youve-rooted-now-what-n00bs-guide-post-root.html).  It reportedly works fine with FRG83D.

Comment: I downloaded twice and got the same result.  Thanks for the link to the thread.  I don't know how I missed that one on DroidForums.net